# Increasing nesting level for parameters and global xparse macros?

Tags: nesting, xparse

This is kind of a double question but closely connected in my case.
Inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55769/14159 I tried to make an improved version which allows additional parameters for the defined symbols.

This is my current code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% colorize to distinguish original and renewed command
\NewDocumentCommand{\defsym}{mmmmm} {%
    \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{#2}{%
        \RenewDocumentCommand{#1}{#2}{\textcolor{blue}{#4}}
        \nomenclature{$#1$}{#5}
        \textcolor{red}{#3}
    }
}

\defsym\Uk{O{k}}{U_{#1}}{U_{##1}}{Some variable}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\noindent$\Uk[j]$,$\Uk,$ $\Uk[p], \Uk[q]$ and $\Uk[r]$
\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

---

[image: Result of the code above]

---

Now to the two problems I have are

1. The double definition `#3` and `#4` is very ugly, is there some macro which increases the nesting level, i.e. which adds one # to each parameter?
   So that I could write `\incnest{#3}` instead of `#4`
2. The `\RenewDocumentCommand` definition is not global so all U's except the `\Uk[q]` are red. Is there some equivalent to `\global` or `\gdef` in xparse. I found something similar for `\renewcommand` in [\global\renewcommand equivalent of \global\def](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51733/global-renewcommand-equivalent-of-global-def) but it's a bit hacky.

Any tricks or workarounds to get it working are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem of global redefinition can't be solved with `\RenewDocumentCommand`; with deeper `expl3` programming, it can be done by setting a switch (a boolean).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% colorize to distinguish original and renewed command
\ExplSyntaxOn
% #1 = command name
% #2 = definition
% #3 = default optional argument
% #4 = description
\NewDocumentCommand{\defsym}{mmmm}
  {
   \bool_new:c { g_buergi_sym_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _bool }
   \bool_gset_false:c { g_buergi_sym_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _bool }
   \buergi_defsym:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \buergi_defsym:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
 {
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{O{#3}}
   {
    \bool_if:cTF  { g_buergi_sym_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _bool }
     { \textcolor{blue}{#2} }
     {
      \textcolor{red}{#2}
      \nomenclature{$#1$}{#4}
      \bool_gset_true:c { g_buergi_sym_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _bool }
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\defsym\Uk{U_{#1}}{k}{Some variable}
\defsym\Ak{A(#1)}{k}{Another}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\noindent $\Uk[j]$, $\Uk$, $\Uk[p]$, $\Uk[q]$ and $\Uk[r]$

\noindent $\Ak$, $\Ak[n]$
\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

As you see, you can give in the second argument any token list with `#1` representing the optional argument, that I've placed third. Just personal preference, if you want to switch the second and third arguments, just change the first definition into

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\defsym}{mmmm}
  {
   \bool_new:c { g_buergi_sym_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _bool }
   \bool_gset_false:c { g_buergi_sym_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _bool }
   \buergi_defsym:nnnn { #1 } { #3 } { #2 } { #4 }
  }
```

The command `\defsym` first defines a boolean switch with a name based on the first argument and sets it to false; then executes the core function which does the required `\NewDocumentCommand`; so `\Uk` is defined to do its normal job in blue color if the boolean is true, while it does its job in red color. annotates in the nomenclature file the usage and *globally* sets the boolean to true.

[image]

Comment: I've also thought of some flag approach but I thought some simple redefinition would be easier, but this seems not to be the case. Thanks a lot, I'll test your code and accept it as answer as soon as I understand the fancy expl3 syntax, never used it so far. I can't even find a good reference for all these commands, is there some good place to look things up?

Comment: @buergi Fire up `texdoc expl3` and `texdoc interface3`. Redefining might be done, but it exposes you to the problem of doubling the `#` tokens.

Comment: @egrep thank you so much for your effort. With your solution I don't need the doubling any more, it's working as expected without the ugly duplicate argument.  I changed `O{#3}` to `#3` as it allows to define symbols with multiple optional arguments (the reason why I used xparse). It seems to be the perfect solution even if it looks a bit ugly :) thanks a lot.

Comment: sorry for misspelling your name, guess I used the unix command-line too much :) ans special thanks for the note about `interface3.pdf`. It's really hard to find the reference if one does not know its name especially since interface3 is not a very obvious name for it.