# automatic nomenclature breaks with subfigure

Tags: macros, captions, subfloats, nomenclature

I am using the method recommended in 
[List of symbols/abbreviations and macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55767/list-of-symbols-abbreviations-and-macros)
to automatically generate an entry to the nomenclature (nomencl package) when I first use a command, i.e.

```
\defsym{\Rn}{\mathbb{R}^n}
[...]
the first occurance $\Rn$ generates an orrurance in the nomenclature,
[...]
the second occurance $\Rn$ does not.
```

This works nicely, and as in the second version described in [List of symbols/abbreviations and macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55767/list-of-symbols-abbreviations-and-macros) it also works for `\section{\Rn}` and in figure captions, however it fails when used in subfigures `\subfigure[\Rn]{}` if that is the first occurrence of the macro.

A minimum example to demonstrate the error:

```
\errorcontextlines2
\documentclass[paper=a4,11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[refpage,noprefix]{nomencl}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\defsym}[3][]{\def#2{%
  \ifx\protect\@unexpandable@protect
    #3%
  \else
    \nomenclature{$#3$}{#1}\gdef#2{#3}#3%
  \fi}
}
\makeatother
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
\defsym{\MeshMacro}{{\cal M}^{\rm mac}}
% $\MeshMacro$ works nicely
\begin{figure}
\subfigure[$\MeshMacro$ goes to hell]{ }
\end{figure}
\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

and the error message is

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=15000].
\nomenclature ->\protect \@nomenclature 

\MeshMacro ...cal M}^{\rm mac}\else \nomenclature 
                                                  {${\cal M}^{\rm mac}$}{}\g...

\MeshMacro ...al M}^{\rm mac}$}{}\gdef \MeshMacro 
                                                  {{\cal M}^{\rm mac}}{\cal ...
...
l.20 \subfigure[$\MeshMacro$ goes to hell]{ }
```

How can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has two faces. First of all the command `\MeshMacro` is fragile, so it should be protected. Hence

```
\subfigure[$\protect\MeshMacro$ goes to hell]{ }
```

will do; but, since the object is typeset in a box inside a box, the usage of `\MeshMacro` will not be recorded in the nomenclature file.

However, the problem with the first appearance of `\MeshMacro` in the subfloat caption can't be solved, because it's a standard TeX feature.

On the other hand, with floating objects one is never sure where they'll fall and the first appearance might end up after the object is used in the text. My suggestion is to avoid such macros in captions.

Note that `\cal` and `\rm` are obsolete commands and you should write

```
\defsym{\MeshMacro}{\mathcal{M}^\mathrm{mac}}
```

using the "officially supported" commands. Also `subfigure` is obsolete, use `subfig` or `subcaption` (they have different syntax, though).

Comment: switching from the `subfigure` package to `subcaption` solved my problem without the need to add `protect`. Thanks a lot.